# How do I play my HTC 3d videos on my 3d TV?

Tags: smart-tv, htc-evo-3d, stereo-video

I have an LG 47LM6200 HD 1080p 3d TV. I have an HTC3d phone. How do I get the videos  to play on my TV?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! As this is an Android specific site, you cannot expect us all to know the features of the TV device you're using – which would help us giving you pointers. Is that a SmartTV? Is it DLNA compatible? If the answer at least to the last is "yes", you might wish to take a look at my list of [DLNA / uPnP Server and Clients](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_dlna). Running a DLNA server on your Android device, that can feed the video to your TV then.

Comment: Sorry, it is a smart TV. I contacted LG support and the chat guy after a half hour told me they're not compatible sorry. I asked him how to I connect any external 3d device and he logged out. I should post the chat as I have a copy of it. You'd probably get a kick out of it. Anyway, it is a smart tv. It is capable of playing 3d. My phone takes 3d videos in "side by side 3d" format. What do I do to connect the two? Any help you can lend would be appreciated. Thanks for trying to help. @Izzy

Comment: According to the [product page](http://www.lg.com/us/tvs/lg-47LM6200-led-tv) (a simple [google for "LG 47LM6200 dlna"](https://www.google.com/search?q=LG+47LM6200+dlna) has that as first hit), the device is DLNA compatible. LG should really check their support staff for competence (they've got some very competent staff members – but they are not always easy to find)... OK, with that detail, I can setup an answer for you. Give me a few minutes to get it ready :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [LG 47LM6200](http://www.lg.com/us/tvs/lg-47LM6200-led-tv) is DLNA compatible (Movie/Photo/Music), all you need for that is a DLNA server on your Android device. On my website you can find a list of apps for that: check with [DLNA / uPnP Server and Clients](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_dlna). To make it easier for you, let me pick the most promising candidate:

**[BubbleUPnP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp)** is both, DLNA server and client – which means you can use it to "send and receive". For your case, you can pick local media from your Android device and stream it to your TV. Which can be done two ways even:

### Variant 1: Use your TV to control

Start the app. Then check on your TV where the DLNA client is, have it look for available sources, pick your Android device from that list, and browse available media. It should allow you to access any movie, photo, or audio file to play.

### Variant 2: Use your Android device to control

This will be the easier variant – at least easier to handle on "daily use". Switch on your TV, then again, start *BubbleUPnP*. It should allow you to pick a "media renderer" (first screenshot below: the first item in the menu on the left side) – your TV should appear in that list, pick it. Now browse your local media (same menu, two items further down), and select what you want to play. Once you've hit "play", the selected file should be streamed to your TV.

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]
<sup>*BubbleUPnP* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp); click images for larger variants)</sup>

This way you couldn't only stream your movies, but also music or your photos. The latter even as slideshow, if you like. And more: if you decide to buy the [license](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bubblesoft.android.bubbleupnp.unlocker), you could even stream stuff from the Internet; the free version of the app gives you the chance to try that first, but has a time limit on it.

Comment: Actually it didn't give me the solution exactly but it put me on the right path so I thank you for your help and awarded you a correct answer. I ended up enabling DLNA on the TV.  I activated it on my htc 3d and shared the folders. Walah they appeared on the tv and I was able to play them. The tv automatically recognized the files that were 3d as 3d and played them in that mode. Everything worked out great. Thank you for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: Oh my – nobody thinks of the simple solutions: you hadn't turned on DLNA on the TV? I hadn't thought of that (always thought it would be on by default), my bad. Glad you found a solution – and glad I at least brought you on the right path to it. Thanks for letting me know – and enjoy! :)